Rotate ads by time in a single category
function getRotatingOrder($items_count = 5) {
    // Calculate the number of hours since the start time
    $hours = floor(time() / 3600);

    // Calculate the number of rotations
    $rotation = $hours % $items_count;

    // Create ORDER BY expression for SQL
    $orderBy = "ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN (id % {$items_count}) = {$rotation} THEN 0
    WHEN (id % {$items_count}) > {$rotation} THEN (id % {$items_count})
    ELSE (id % {$items_count} + {$items_count})
    END ASC, date_added DESC";

    return $orderBy;
}
$order_by = getRotatingOrder(10); // rotation for 10 ads

I have an advertising site that consists of 2 categories. The code I shared loops the ads, however, it loops the ads in 2 categories. I want it to loop only in one category.
I also want all the ads to loop in the 1st category without specifying the number of ads. Category 1 should loop in this category. Category 2 should not loop in this category.

somewhere in the sql query (that you haven't fully revealed) include a condition such as where category = 1 so you only return the wanted information
